# Setup up Facebook like barrier

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I created a "fan page" for my photography, and want to set it up so that people have to like the page to gain access to comment on the page's wall and photos. I cannot find any settings to do this, how do I do it? I know another girl has hers set up that way and would like to do that with mine.

Comment: What app are you talking about? Facebook?

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://www.binkd.com/social-media/how-to-hide-content-until-someone-likes-your-facebook-page-with-iframes/

Answer (score 1):

Previously, it was possible to disallow users from commenting before liking a page. But this is now not possible *within official Facebook* settings. All Facebook page walls are open to the public to comment.

In order to accomplish preventing someone from commenting you will need to set up a like "paywall" via programming.

Comment: Even this will be unavailable once facebook migrates all pages to the timeline layout on 3/30/12